# JavaScript, sort object by latest date and time values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Beginner here.
I want to sort the whole object array, by date and time values. Latest date and time first.

My problem. 
Not sure how to sort with different key values, by date and time.
Example: I have key values **start**, **stop** and **turn**. I want to sort this by date and time. I would still like to keep the key values as a reference to that value.

```
{
  "start 0": "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z",
  "start 1": "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z",
  "start 2": "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z",
  "stop 0": "2017-10-23T21:40:27Z",
  "stop 1": "2017-10-24T03:47:20Z",
  "stop 2": "2017-10-24T09:42:34Z",
  "turn 0": "2017-10-22T16:02:51Z",
  "turn 1": "2017-10-23T22:13:56Z",
  "turn 2": "2017-10-23T03:19:20Z"
}
```

I am using moment.js

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "start 0": "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z",
  "start 1": "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z",
  "start 2": "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z",
  "stop 0": "2017-10-23T21:40:27Z",
  "stop 1": "2017-10-24T03:47:20Z",
  "stop 2": "2017-10-24T09:42:34Z",
  "turn 0": "2017-10-22T16:02:51Z",
  "turn 1": "2017-10-23T22:13:56Z",
  "turn 2": "2017-10-23T03:19:20Z"
}
```

is an object and since javascript objects have no order, sorting doesn't make sense

Answer (score 0):

What you have is an object, but if we assume you have the following array:
var datesArr =["2017-10-24T03:15:36Z","2017-10-24T03:15:36Z","2017-10-24T15:41:27Z"];

What you need in order to sort those is:
datesArr.sort((a,b)=> new Date(b) - new Date(a))

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
res =
{ 'start 0': '2017-10-24T03:15:36Z',
  'start 1': '2017-10-24T09:13:44Z',
  'start 2': '2017-10-24T15:41:27Z',
  'stop 0': '2017-10-23T21:40:27Z',
  'stop 1': '2017-10-24T03:47:20Z',
  'stop 2': '2017-10-24T09:42:34Z',
  'turn 0': '2017-10-22T16:02:51Z',
  'turn 1': '2017-10-23T22:13:56Z',
  'turn 2': '2017-09-23T03:19:20Z' }

// console.log(res);
myarr = []
Object.keys(res).forEach( key => {
   console.log(key+" = "+res[key]);
   myarr.push({ 'key': key, 'stamp': res[key]});
}
);
// console.log(myarr);
myarr.sort(function(a, b) { 
    return new Date(a.stamp) - new Date(b.stamp) > 0;
})

// console.log(sorted);
for(var i in myarr){

  console.log(myarr[i]);

}
```

repl [link](https://repl.it/NQF6)

Answer (score 0):

```
var array=[{
  "date": "2017-10-24T03:15:36Z"},
           {"date": "2017-10-24T09:13:44Z"},
           {"date": "2017-10-24T15:41:27Z"},
           {"date": "2017-10-23T21:40:27Z"},{
  "date": "2017-10-23T03:19:20Z"}
]

array.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(b.date) - new Date(a.date);
});
```

try something like this , keys should be same in every object